# How to display just the month in a date picker control

Tags: vb6, datepicker

I want to display just the month in datecontrol, like

```
datecontrol1 = January, February ... december
```

I dont want to diplay `day, year and time`.

How to do this?

Comment: Set Format and Custom format properties.

Comment: @AVD, In datecontrol i cannot find the custom format properties

Comment: Not sure about `DataControl` in vb. Is it a DatePicker or custom control?

Comment: I don't think "datecontrol" is a standard VB6 component. Is it a user control or a third party AciveX perhaps?

Comment: There is still no need for "need vb code help" It's implied int he fact you're asking a question tagged [vb6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `DTPicker` then you can select it's property `Format` to `3 - dtpCustom` and set the 'CustomFormat' to 'MMMM' like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's the `DTPicker` control found in `Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2`, you can set the `Format` to `3 - dtpCustom` and set the `CustomFormat` to `MMMM`.